# Where do you put client-side source files when using grunt and maven?

Tags: java, javascript, maven, build, gruntjs

Typically on a Java project using Maven, you place client-side source files in `src/main/webapp`. This directory includes your html, css, scripts, images, etc.

However, many grunt projects tend to place these files on the root. It's as if Grunt was designed with the idea that your project *is* the client-side application, not part of a large server-side project, such as using Java with Spring.

Given a Java project using Maven, where would be the best place to put your web-related source files?

Do you place them in `src/main/webapp`?

Do you make another directory altogether, such as `src/web`, and then on a build, copy everything to `src/main/webapp`?

My goal is to make the client-side build tool as transparent as possible. I guess the ideal case is to simply work from `src/main/webapp` as I have been doing all along - this is pretty unobtrusive to the way my project is currently setup.

However, if I work from `src/main/webapp`, I know that I will need to distinguish between src and build directories somehow anyway. I'm sure my html files can stay where they are, but there's definitely going to be a conflict of interest here with javascript and css files, and maybe images too.

Does it make sense to literally have a 100% separate source folder from `src/main/webapp`? Is there a way to do continuous building/copying/syncing of the application as you modify files, from `src/web` to `src/main/webapp`? Will this be inconvenient and cause frustrations and problems? Is it slow?

I would like any advice on the subject. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put grunt/bower/etc. files for Maven-based spring project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445148/where-to-put-grunt-bower-etc-files-for-maven-based-spring-project)

Comment: Can you either delete your duplicate question or tell u s how this one is different?

Comment: @Anzeo Link you provided is unreachable

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Put UI resources in src/main/webapp:

This is a quick-n-dirty solution popular on Github. It helps to keep example projects small and concise. In this case, usually people put the `package.json`, `bower.json`, `Gruntfile.js` and `.bowerrc` in the maven project's root directory, where the `.bowerrc` says to install components into `src/main/webapp/bower_components`.

If you have a task that minifies/transforms resources, the transformed resources can go to a new directory like `src/main/webapp/dist`. Then use something like [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) to make your app use the resources in the `dist` directory.

If your application will use a security framework (like, say, Spring Security), you might want all your resources in `src/main/webapp` so that the security framework can regulate access to those resources. However you can still achieve this using Option 2 by having a grunt task that copies the necessary resources into `src/main/webapp`.

#### Pros

- Common approach on GitHub. Keeps everything in one project.

#### Cons

- The version of files getting served by your server is a *copy* of those in `src/main/webapp`, so changing a file in `src/main/webapp` isn't immediately reflected in your deployed app. To get hot reloading, you need to use something like `grunt-contrib-*` stuff.
- Frontend and backend code is all mixed together. Harder for two different teams to work on the code base.

### Option 2: Put UI resources in a separate project:

You can achieve better project organization by keeping the UI and backend in completely separate projects. In this case the UI and the maven project would likely be sibling directories.

Then when deploying to a server, you either:

1. deploy both projects separately (call them `myproject-ui` and `myproject-services`). The javascript in `myproject-ui` makes RESTful service calls to `myproject-services/**`.
2. Use a grunt task to copy necessary resources to `src/main/webapp`, then deploy your (one) project.

#### Pros

1. The backend and the frontend are separated as much as possible
2. The frontend maintains the workflow and directory structure found in most client-side example apps, as you mentioned
3. "Deploying" the UI is a simple matter of creating a symlink from your server's deployment directory to you UI source code. Changing any UI code is automatically reflected in the deployed app.
4. You can have several different UIs deployed simultaneously (maybe you have `myproject-admin-ui` and `myproject-user-ui`). You could hit either one simply by visiting

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/myproject-admin-ui
   http://localhost:8080/myproject-user-ui
   ```